# Azure kubernetes - java spring app & managed identity to access key vault?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to Dockerize the java spring application and deploy it in Azure kubernetes. This application is connected to the database and currently it reads the connection string from the configuration file.

As this application will be Dockerized and deployed on AKS, I want to read the connection string from the Azure Key vault using managed identity.

Are there any samples available which demonstrates the above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the connection as a keyvault secret, then use the java sdk to get it.

Make sure you have [added your MSI(managed identity) to the keyvault access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal), then use the code below.

1.[Create secret client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/security-keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-java-stable#create-secret-client)

It uses [`DefaultAzureCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#authenticating-with-defaultazurecredential) to authenticate, don't set the environment vars, then it will use your MSI to authenticate automatically, you can also use [`ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.managedidentitycredentialbuilder?view=azure-java-stable) instead of `DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder`, specify the [`clientId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.managedidentitycredentialbuilder.clientid?view=azure-java-stable) of your MSI.

```
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;

SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
    .vaultUrl("<your-key-vault-url>")
    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
    .buildClient();
```

2.[Retrieve a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/security-keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-java-stable#retrieve-a-secret)

```
KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.getSecret("<secret-name>");
System.out.printf("Retrieved secret with name \"%s\" and value \"%s\"%n", secret.getName(), secret.getValue());
```

For more details see - [Azure Key Vault Secret client library for Java - Version 4.2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/security-keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-java-stable)

Comment: Thank you. How do I add multiple managed identity to an azure kubernetes cluster?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar I don't think you can do that, you can just use a system-assigned MSI or user-assigned MSI for it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar If you want to use different service principals to auth, I think you could use [ClientSecretCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-java-stable) directly, just create several AD Apps in Azure AD.